# Webform Confirmation Page URL alias tokens

Tags: 8, webforms

From several things I have read, it seems like I have this correct, but it doesn't seem to be working. On my form settings page under "Confirmation page URL alias", I have:

```
/quote/thank-you?loc=[webform_submission:values:location:value]
```

When I submit the form, I'm taken to:

```
/quote/thank-you%3Floc%3D%5Bwebform_submission%3Avalues%3Alocationl%3Avalue%5D?token
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not replacing that value? Does the fact that my form is paged have anything to do with it? The element I'm looking for ("location") is on a page called "provider". Does that need to be represented in my token somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Does that field support tokens?

Comment: Or query strings for that matter? It seems maybe neither given the url-encoded outcome. Or maybe the encoding happens first, hence no token replacement